# Multiple counts on one object in an SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there have been many posts on this subject but none seem to quite apply.  So I will try to be as descriptive as I can.  I am trying to create an object which counts the number of times it has been viewed, exported and commented on.  In my mind, first the query has to find the object then it has to pull the record(row) of counts from the Impala DB.

It retrieves this information from one of 2 systems, 'sys_a' or 'sys_b'.
So in my semi-pseudo-code:

```
select object, sum(case when action = 'viewed' and (system = 'sys_a' or 'sys_b') then 1 else 0 end) viewCount,
               sum(case when action = 'exported' and (system = 'sys_a' or 'sys_b') then 1 else 0 end) exportCount,
               sum(case when action = 'commented' and (system = 'sys_a' or 'sys_b') then 1 else 0 end) commentCount
from events;
```

Unfortunately, when I have duplicate, exported objects in my `events` table, which I know I have, all my counts are 0.

In other words - my Object 3421AA2B has been exported 13 times but it still has a count of 0.
I know this because if I do a simple

```
select count(*)
from events
where object = '3421AA2B' and action = 'exported' and (system = 'sys_a' or system = 'sys_b');
```

My count shows up as 13.

Comment: you must add GROUP BY object;

Comment: can't see why dupe records would matter. you're not grouping, just doing some basic filtering. if nothing else, dupes would just INCREASE the count, not zero-out. and note that since you're doing the SAME sys_a/sys_b test in all of the sum(case statements, you might as well just move the sys_a/sys_b test into the general `where` clause.

Comment: added `group by`, didn't matter.  I did remove the braces around the `system` and now I am properly getting `objects`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `system =` in `or` statments...

```
select object, sum(case when action = 'viewed' and (system = 'sys_a' or system ='sys_b') then 1 else 0 end) viewCount,
               sum(case when action = 'exported' and (system = 'sys_a' or system ='sys_b') then 1 else 0 end) exportCount,
               sum(case when action = 'commented' and (system = 'sys_a' or system ='sys_b') then 1 else 0 end) commentCount from events;
```

check case statements outputs :

```
SELECT object,
  case when action = 'viewed' then 1 else 0 end as view,
  case when action = 'exported' then 1 else 0 end as export,
  case when action = 'commented' then 1 else 0 end as comment
FROM events
WHERE system = 'sys_a' OR system = 'sys_b'
```

I removed system form case statements like Marc B suggested

Comment: sorry that was just a typo, it really is there

Comment: Ok, that's great, now I'm getting either one's or zero's in each view/export/comment column.  I added the `sum` around each `case` statement as well as the `group by` statement at the end and I got some numbers.  Thanks.  They don't quite line up with a simple `select COUNT(*)` on `object = `

Comment: Couldn't edit my comments above but I was missing another filtering field.  Awesome job!  I got the numbers I expected.  Thanks.

Comment: @jnbbender, So you had it all right in the first place ? What was wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101321/discussion-between-jnbbender-and-dionys).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why that, but anyhow, I would try to add

```
GROUP BY object;
```

to your query.. 
since without it, you will get unexpected results.

Only after this modification can you try and understand what to fix next.